# Custom Resources: Is it okay to reapply settings every time?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I've had a few opportunities to create custom DSC resources come up lately where I am unable to verify if the configuration has already been applied. Two examples are:

- Setting up an application service account with username/password. I can't read the password to verify it is setup properly.
- Adding access for an account to a RSA key container (via `aspnet_regiis -pa`).

While I could be missing something that would help these specific scenarios... I still have the general question: Is it okay to reapply settings every time a DSC configuration is applied? In other words, have `Test-TargetResource` always return `$false`...

[MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249927.aspx) says:

> invoking the Set-TargetResource function more than once in a sequence
>   with the same parameter values is always equivalent to invoking it
>   once.

...so reapplying seems okay. It'd probably just waste a bit of performance.

Comment: Shameless promotion: check out the [Carbon_Permission](https://bitbucket.org/splatteredbits/carbon/src/3bb1b4ef5fb4e5f49921c3bd04fa268bf41e8e7e/Carbon/DscResources/Carbon_Permission/?at=default) DSC resource. It will correctly test if an RSA key container has permissions on it or not. It uses [Test-Permission](https://bitbucket.org/splatteredbits/carbon/src/3bb1b4ef5fb4e5f49921c3bd04fa268bf41e8e7e/Carbon/Security/Test-Permission.ps1?at=default) to check private key permissions. These will be part of [Carbon](http://get-carbon.org) 2.0, eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regarding the Question at Hand

I think that in general it is ok to always apply, as you have surmised, but of course always be aware of any side effects.

For example, is there a password policy in effect that forces account passwords to be reset every N days? If so, you may in effect be nullifying that policy inadvertently (this is just an example; in reality it might not make sense when you look closely at my example).

And obviously if your change requires a reboot to take effect, you don't want to always be setting because you'll either not be forcing the reboot and therefore not setting state, or you'll always be rebooting!

#### Logging/Monitoring

Note that if you're doing any kind of monitoring of your system states and drift, then you may have an issue with this approach. I haven't personally gotten there yet, but I could see how having a machine show up as "not in configuration" every 30 to 60 minutes would be a problem.

### Your Scenarios

When it comes to testing the user's password, I believe you can do this. You must already be embedding the password if you're setting it, so instead of trying to read it, try to authenticate as the user using the password you know.

As for the RSA thing.. I'm not familiar with the scenario so I have no idea.

Comment: Agreed. You should try really, really hard to return a correct value from `Test-TargetResource`, but sometimes you can't, like when setting the credentials of a service. Not even Microsoft's own `Service` resource does that. It doesn't handle service account password changes.